# Add Image dynamically in runtime - Unity 5

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

In my unity based Android game I wish to add the image dynamically based on the number of questions in each level. The image is shown for reference. Each correct answer will be marked in green and the wrong one in red. I am new to unity and trying hard to find steps to achieve this.

Any help with an example for this requirement will be a great help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote a script for dynamically creating buttons based on each level. What I did was creating the first button on the scene and adding the other buttons based on the first one. Below is the shell of my code:

```
// tutorialButton and levelButtons are public variables which can be set from Inspector
RectTransform rect = tutorialButton.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();

for (int i = 1; i < levelSize; i++) {
    // Instantiate the button dynamically
    GameObject newButton = GameObject.Instantiate (tutorialButton); 

    // Set the parent of the new button (In my case, the parent of tutorialButton)
    newButton.transform.SetParent (levelButtons.transform);

    //Set the scale to be the same as the tutorialButton
    newButton.transform.localScale = tutorialButton.transform.localScale;

    //Set the position to the right of the tutorialButton
    Vector3 position = tutorialButton.transform.localPosition;
    position.x += rect.rect.width*i;
    newButton.transform.localPosition = position;
}
```

I am not exactly sure if this is the right approach as it may or may not give unexpected results depending on different screen sizes and your canvas, but hopefully it gives you an idea about dynamically creating objects.

Comment: Where to attach this script .  in canvas or panel ?

Comment: As long as you set tutorialButton and levelButton objects from inspector, it actually does not matter where you attach the script. It does not use any of the properties of the Gameobject which the script is attached. (In my case I had a script which handles all the game logic and it was attached to an empty Gameobject and this piece of code was in the Start() function, so at the load of each level ( scene) it was called once and created the buttons necessary for the level).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but if you have all the images in the scene under a canvas, with this you just need to drag the canvas on the script and use

`//level-1 is to keep the array notation
FindObjectOfType<NameOfScript>.ChangeColor(level-1,Color.green);`

or you can do also

`//level-1 is to keep the array notation
FindObjectOfType<NameOfScript>.RevertColor(level - 1);`

This is the script:

```
//Keep it private but you still see it in inspector
//#Encapsulation :)
[SerializeField]
private Canvas _canvas;

private Image[] _images;
//keep the original colors in case you want to change back
private Color[] _origColors;

void Start () {
    _images = GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
    _origColors = new Color[_images.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < _images.Length; i++)
    {
        _origColors[i] = _images[i].color;
    }

}
//Reverts the color of the image back to the original
public void RevertToOriginal(int imageIndex)
{
    _images[imageIndex].color = _origColors[imageIndex];
}
//Change to color to the coresponding index, starts from 0
public void ChangeColor(int imageIndex, Color color)
{
    _images[imageIndex].color = color;
}
```

P.S If you want it visible only at the end you can make a method where you enable = (true or false) for the canvas. So you keep it false till the end of the level and you make it true when you want to show, while after every answer you call the ChangeColor depending on the result.
To make it easier you can use:

```
NameOfScript variableName = FindObjectOfType<NameOfScript>();
```

and after that you just call

```
variableName.ChangeColor(level - 1, Color.green);
```

Also it does not matter where you put the script. I would make some kind of manager(empty GameObject) in the scene and put it there.